# Running background job continuously in linux

Tags: linux, command, jobs, job-scheduling

Can anyone suggest how can i run a job in Linux continuously in background?

Task of this job would be review some of the user accounts and see if they are active or not.

Thanks,
Tapan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**CRONTAB!!**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205)

Use the format `* * * * * command`

Here is a helpful resource: [Newbie: Intro to Cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Comment: You might use `@reboot` as the time field.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That should work. and any idea about how to achieve same thing in Aix servers? Well, i will be running it across different servers, so thought to check.