# Perpetual cron job

Tags: php, linux, cron, cron-task

I have developed a php script, that I want to run continuously.

For example, the script `run.php` executes a list of tasks, but I don't know how long it will take: it can take 30 sec, 1 min, 2 min, or more.

The problem is this script can't be executed simultaneous.

So I can't use the cron job because if I setup a cron job every minute, but the script is running during more than 1 minutes, I'll have bugs).

In fact, I want that this cron job to be Perpetual executed : everytime `run.php` is ended, the script `run.php` is reloaded, again and again...

I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Any help please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running background job continuously in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896893/running-background-job-continuously-in-linux)

Comment: @pdexter I believe that this isn't a duplicate of that question. OP clearly states that a concurrent execution of `run.sh` shall not occur. The answer to the question you've referenced does not account for that case.

Comment: hi, yes, it's not a duplicate. funny, you lost more time to find a duplicate question than really reading my question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You've [at least] two options:

- Under `run.php` code, determine if it is already running (by setting some external control system that is checked at the beginning of the script) and setup the crontab job as you described. [I recommend this approach].
- Use something like `(while :; do php run.php; done) &` run it once, and put it inside the `/etc/rc.local` to make it run at every system start. I don't really like this approach, but it's a possible solution.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. for the first point, what do you mean by setting an external control system ? like a value in a file/database. i was thinking to make that, but one thing i'm afraid of is : if i setup a value : on (script is running) and off (script is non running), i should update the value to off at the end of my file run.php . But if the run.php can't go at the end of the file (for any reasons), the value can't be update to off, and then, the script won't be executed. i hope it's clear

Comment: @user3392106 Yes that may present a problem. The perfect solution will grant that the state is always updated. If you cannot grant that, you can still implement a watchdog system, such as, if the state wasn't updated for `n` minutes, then you assume that the script failed to update the state and is no longer running. This isn't perfect and is prone to cause bugs if you're not certain of how long the script may take to run... but it's another approach.

Comment: ok, thank you threadp, i'll do like that. Here the idea ; i will create a txt file with a temporary value. in my script run.php, i will start to test the value in the txt file, if it's empty (or with a timestamp <7 min), i insert the timestamp before my real php script. at the end of the script of run.php, i erase the timestamp (so the file is again empty), because it means that the file execute at the end. If there is a problem, then the file will have the timestamp in the file. and the next run of run.php, this timestamp will help me to know if there were an error or not